# Recalculation the cluster centroids

Tags: python, clustering

I tried to cluster data points by k-medoids where k-centroids/medoids are randomly picked from (X), how those centroids are recalculated when there are some clusters changing by the updating x1? **without reclustering**

lets assume that there is a number if round for updating x1 of X, How are the new centroids picked when the cluster of user 5 is changed to cluster 1? and the cluster of user 0 is changed to cluster 2? (when x1 values are updated) and so on.